# Product Attribute Won't Save

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

Hi i have a product attribute that will not save when changed in the product itself!

Its a multi select, global scope, not required and set for all product types.

In fact another multi select doesn't save either so it seems to be a multi select problem.

Doesn't matter if I select one option or ten it doesn't remember it just says saved sucessfully and then doesn't actually save it!

Does anyone have any ideas or can you suggest where to begin on debugging this?

Cheers!

BUMPING: Any ideas?